# Why datepicker dissapears when scrolling the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

On mobile with safari browser after I show my datepicker (clicking) then if I scroll down to page my datepicker is not appear anymore what can be my issue ?

I'm looking for a way to fix it datepicker ui issue but I couldn't get any result for a week what can be issue please ?

the problem only happens mobile safari browser

```js
function datePicker(){
   
      
        var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
            from = $( "#checkin,.checkin" )
                .datepicker({
                    numberOfMonths: 2,
                    firstDay: 1,
                    minDate: 0,
                    beforeShow:function(){
                        $(this).datepicker("widget").addClass("main-datepicker");
                    }
                })
                .on( "change", function() {
                    to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
                }),
            to = $( "#checkout,.checkout" ).datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                firstDay: 1,
                minDate: 0,
                beforeShow:function(){
                    $(this).datepicker("widget").addClass("main-datepicker");
                }
            })
            .on( "change", function() {
                from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
            });

        function getDate( element ) {
            var date;
            try {
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
            } catch( error ) {
                date = null;
            }

            return date;
        }
   
}

datePicker();
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" id="checkin">
<input type="text" id="checkout">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

[Live Demo](https://www.anitur.com/ucak-bileti)

Comment: can't seem to reproduce the issue, can you provide a screen with the bug?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/iOYYm
ok this datepicker will be dissappear and won't be appear again anymore if I click

Comment: I think the problem is that when someone swipes down, the code considers it as a "click" which makes the datepicker disapear.

Comment: thanks for replying so what do you prefer to fix the issue ?